# Insert data from other column into each row's respective number

Tags: google-sheets

Really new to sheets and what I'm trying to do this:
I have this formula
`=CONCATENATE("<option value=")&("""")&A15&("""")&(">")&A15&("</option>")`
What I need is where it says A15 to add from the column A into each row.
So for example:
A1
A2
A3
etc but I have hundreds of these that I need to automate.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array formula. Put this formula in cell `B1`:

`=filter("<option value = """ & A1:A & """>" & A1:A & "</option>", len(A1:A))`